# how to use onPanResponderMove in PanResponder to prevent crash?

Tags: react-native

I'm creating a game which I need to track user touch event to see if he/she cross an object and do something.
I used onPanResponderMove in PanResponder and all the time user is moving his finger I call a function and check user movement and it works perfectly.
but If a user tries to move a finger for a long time it makes app crash and something like "Maximum call stack size exceeded" happens.

I want to know if I'm doing the correct way or not?
because it seems I use a lot of rams and it causes the problem and crashes.

here is my code:

```
componentWillMount() {    
    let strings = 'a,b,c,d|s,d,f,g|h,b,a,u|m,l,k,o';
    let arrayST = strings.split("|");
    for (i = 0; i < arrayST.length; i++) {
      arrayST[i] = arrayST[i].split(",");
    }
    this.initBoxes(arrayST)

    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: (evt) => {
        this.setState({
          userAnswer: [],
          userAnswerWords: [],
          answerd: false,
        });
      },
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
        const drag = this.getDirectionAndColor(gestureState);
        if (drag != 'No') {
          this.setState({
            findState: 'Proccessing',
          });
        }
      },
      onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
        this.setState({
          findState: 'Finished',
          answerd: true,
          answerCordinate: '',
        });
        if (this.state.userAnswer.join(',') != this.state.correctAnswer) {
          for (let l = 0; l < 16; l++) {
            this.setState(state => {
              state.boxes[l].bgColor = 'transparent'
              return state
            })
          }
        }
      },
    });
  }
```

all the time I'm calling the getDirectionAndColor function.
please help me with your advice.

thanks.